# Why is my init() function not being run? (Automatically adding a toolbar button when installing a Firefox extension but only on first run)

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, toolbar

I keep returning to this problem, and keep on failing to solve it.

I've read tens of pages describing how to do it, and looked at answers such as [How can I make my Firefox extension toolbar button appear automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579656/how-can-i-make-my-firefox-extension-toolbar-button-appear-automatically) on here, but I just can't get this right.

I understand the concept of what I need to do, but the point I have reached is that, while the extension itself works correctly, I cannot get the `init(`) function to run and the load listener doesn't seem to be being added either (I have added `alert`s before and after the `window.top.addEventListener..` code but the `alert`s aren't firing either.

What I want to achieve is the recommended process of adding the toolbar button on install / update but only on first run/install.

My extension consists of:

- `chrome.manifest` and `install.rdf` in the extension root directory.
- a `chrome` folder which contains the other elements (`extensionName.js`, `extensionName.png`, `extensionName.xul`, `extensionName.css` and `icon.png`).
- `prefs.js` in a `defaults/preferences` directory. This contains the `extensions.MyExtensionNameButton.firstRunDone` pref set to `false`.

The extension itself works exactly as required (it includes a toolbar button and right-click context menu items).

My `extensionName.js` file contains the following (with the actual extension functions trimmed out as they are working and would make the question too long):

```
objMyExtensionNameButton = {

    // functions that are called by the .xul are in here,


    init : function() {
      var firstRunPref = "extensions.MyExtensionNameButton.firstRunDone";
      alert("init function run");
      if (!Application.prefs.getValue(firstRunPref)) {
        Application.prefs.setValue(firstRunPref, true);
        // all the rest of the first run code goes here.
        alert("this is the first run");
      } else {
        alert("this is NOT the first run");
      }
   }  
};

window.top.addEventListener("load", function() { objMyExtensionNameButton.init(); }, false);
```

The relevant part of the xul that includes the .js file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css"
  href="chrome://MyExtensionNameButton/content/button.css"?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay >
<overlay id="MyExtensionNameButton-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<script type="application/javascript"
  src="chrome://MyExtensionNameButton/content/MyExtensionNameButton.js"/>

<!-- Firefox -->
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
  <toolbarbutton id="MyExtensionNameButton"/>
  </toolbarpalette>


<!-- button details -->
<toolbarbutton id="MyExtensionNameButton"

...etc etc etc...
```

I cannot seem  to get anything to run when the extension is installed or when Firefox starts - clicking on extension options in the toolbar button or the right click menu runs those functions without any problem - those functions are all included in an object.

I've tried moving the `init()` function both inside and outside of that object and, I believe, calling it correctly.

The other odd thing is that I don't seem to see any errors from the extension in the console (I wasn't seeing any errors when I hadn't added the `default/preferences/prefs.js` file to the `.xpi` either, so something seems amiss there as well).

Thanks,

FM

Comment: That should be working.I have the same code in my extension and it works. Don't know what you might have wrong there.

Comment: It doesn't even look as though the `init` function is getting called. I've got it to the point where the JS syntax is correct so my other functions work fine, but the `alert` in the `init` function doesn't pop up.

Comment: it could be something preventing the alert (this is just a guess :p). have you tried validating if the pref is changed or not?

Comment: Yes, I've checked in `prefs.js` and in `about:config` and there is no mention of `extensions.MyExtensionNameButton.firstRunDone` in there. `MyExtensionNameButton` is listed in the `extensions.installCache` and `extensions.enabledAddons`, but the new value hasn't been added. I've now also tried moving the init function out of `objMyExtensionNameButton` and calling it directly in the listener but still nothing. I've also tried with and without the `top` in the `window.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

In your default `prefs.js`, you should add

```
pref('extensions.MyExtensionNameButton.firstRunDone', false);
```

Since the pref `extensions.MyExtensionNameButton.firstRunDone` does not exist, the call to `Application.prefs.getValue(firstRunPref)` should have been failing.

If you open up the error console, Ctrl+Shift+j, you should see the related error.

Comment: Thanks @Kashif, that's got me a step further - the `firstRunDone` pref is now being added to Firefox and set to `false`.  What's odd is that the error wasn't showing up in the error console at all - I was getting no errors reported from my extension! It still seems that my `init()` function isn't running at all, though, as the value isn't then being set to `true`. None of the alerts that I've inserted in and around the `init()` function for debug are firing either.

Comment: @FatMonk How did you include the js file in your ````extensionName.xul```` file? Can you add the code from xul file to the question?

Comment: I've added the relevant bit of the `.xul` file to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kashif, does the `.xul` include of the `.js` file look correct to you? I'm still not getting any further and I'm still not seeing errors in the console.

Comment: @FatMonk Yes it is correct. I cannot see why this is not working. What do you mean by "If I remove everything from the window.top line down the extension works as expected"

Comment: Hi @Kashif, that paragraph was actually from earlier on in the problem - I had a copy and paste typo in the JavaScript at one point that meant the `objMyExtensionNameButton` object wasn't well formed when I added the `addEventListener` command after it (I'd got my commas and semi-colons confused). I've updated the question so it's more accurate and less confusing now.

Comment: Then there should not be any problem. It looks like your ````objMyExtensionNameButton```` still have some js syntax errors.

Comment: Hi @Kashif, I've run JS-Lint on the script and the only errors appear to be: `Line 1, column 1: 'objMyExtensionNameButton' was used before it was defined.`, `'gContextMenu' was used before it was defined.`, `Expected 'String' and instead saw ''''.`, `'gContextMenu' was used before it was defined.`, `Unexpected 'else' after 'return'.`, `Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.`, `'Application' was used before it was defined., Empty block.`. None of those seem particularly critical..

Comment: I've now tried removing all content from the `objMyExtensionNameButton` functions and replaced it with a bunch of `alerts` so that I can see if there are any syntax errors that may be tripping the script up. The alerts fire when expected when I interact with the button or context menu, but that preference variable is NOT getting set to `true` by the `init()` function. There is no indication that `init` has run at all.

Comment: Is this answer still valid with the current Firefox SDK as of 2016? I am wondering because the new SDK does not use .xul anymore, and there is even a migration guide to migrate from .xul to SDK (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/XUL_Migration_Guide), however, there is nothing mentioned how to add the extension icon to the toolbar automatically using the new approach. All information I found on the web is referring to the old .xul approach. For example, there is not prefs.js anymore in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension

Comment: @MathiasConradt: Yeap this is not valid for WebExtensions. For your example, you need to [specify a BrowserAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Specifying_the_browser_action) to have a toolbar button with image.

Comment: @Kashif I did create a browser action in the manifest.json, but the problem with that alone is that it does not always gets added to the toolbar necessarily - I mean automatically right after the installation of the extension. Sometimes you first need to right-click the toolbar, click "customize...", and then drag the icon to the toolbar manually. This happens especially when installing the extension from the AOM (Add-Ons store of Mozilla). When adding the .xpi locally during development, sometimes the icon occurs in the toolbar right away, sometimes it doesn't. I meanwhile found a solution...

Comment: .. It's necessary to create a background js script, and then trigger the icon to be shown in there. This is the code that finally worked: http://pastebin.com/DwS9wUVz (in the end, I decided to use a page action instead of a browser action though) for my extension (http://www.commentanywhere.org/)