# Are there any best practices to help your users install your Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox

Are there any best practices to help your users install your Firefox extension?

I have a Firefox extension in the form of a button. The actual install is roughly OK, but getting users to

- click on the Firefox menu
- click Customize
- drag and drop the button to their toolbar
- close the menu

is just insane.

Do you know any services that did that in a specially clever way, or any best practice resource to lose as little users as possible?

Comment: It seems that you're asking for a technically different way, rather than a UX question on what the way should be.  That makes it outside of the scope of this site, and something you should probably ask on StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation on the Firefox side, there is a way to do it automatically for the user:
[How can I make my Firefox extension toolbar button appear automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579656/how-can-i-make-my-firefox-extension-toolbar-button-appear-automatically)

Google Chrome did this by default, so it's more something that you have to add in your extension to have a consistent experience.

Pocket does that automatically. They have a grey icon, in line with the default icons, which makes it easy to miss it altogether.